# Linux timeout function with wget

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I am executing wget with timeout of 4min:

```
timeout 4m wget -c -O "/aci/mnt/$ID/$ID.sra" $URL
writeLog "wget exit..."
RESULTCODE=$?
                
if [ $RESULTCODE -eq 0 ]; then 
    writeLog "wget Success!"
    completeMessage
    postOrchestrator
    writeLog "exit RESULTCODE=$RESULTCODE"
    exit $RESULTCODE
elif [ $RESULTCODE -eq 124 ]; then
    writeLog "Timeout of wget occurred; abandon message!"
    writeLog "exit RESULTCODE=$RESULTCODE"
    exit $RESULTCODE
else
    writeLog "wget failed! RESULTCODE=$RESULTCODE"
fi
```

The downloads can take a long time and sometimes hang. The timeout is intended to abort the download and start it again where I left off. wget is stopping at 4min.

However, **the response code is 0, indicating success**. How do I get the timeout to indicate something other than 0 when a timeout is invoked ?

Comment: How do you check return code?

Comment: I updated codeblock to answer question

Comment: Does `$URL` contain `&`? If yes, it's interpreted by shell, the command goes into background and returned code is 0. But it doesn't wait and returns immediately. Try `"$URL"` in double quotes. If it doesn't help, check `type timeout` and make sure it is `/usr/bin/timeout`, not an alias or some kind of builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...I was calling a function before I capture the RESULTCODE - which reset the 124 to 0. The result code is now 124.